# How to draw line from edge of rectangle to the opposite side

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to define command which draw line from edge of a rectangle occupies page area to the opposite side.

To draw the line I do some manual adjustments to connect both sides with rectangle

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\margin{2cm}

\def\Sep{2mm}

\def\Line{\par\medskip\noindent\hspace{-2.7mm}\tikz\draw[double,double distance=1mm](0,0)--(\textwidth+4.1mm,0);\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=\margin}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw([shift={(\margin-\Sep-1mm,\margin-\Sep-1mm)}]current page.south west)rectangle([shift={(-\margin+\Sep+1mm,-\margin+\Sep+1mm)}]current page.north east);
\draw([shift={(\margin-\Sep,\margin-\Sep)}]current page.south west)rectangle([shift={(-\margin+\Sep,-\margin+\Sep)}]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]

\Line

\lipsum[1]

\Line

\lipsum[1]

\Line

\end{document}
```

Which produce

[image]

My question is how can I define `\Line` command to obtain automatic adjustments of length when I modify `\Sep` and `\margin`.

Comment: Why are you building the boxes like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think that boxes like that are easily made with `tcolorbox`, next code shows a possible solution to this problem.

As OP wants to draw a line in an unknown vertical place on a page and horizontaly delimited by a rectangle defined by two corners.

First we need to know where the lines has to be drawn, this problem is solved with a counter which is incremented with every line and whose value fixes a `TiKZ` coordinate's name.

As the rectangle size depends on `\Sep` and `\margin` variables, two auxiliar coordinates are declared. These coordinates will help to drawn the line with length adjusted to margins.

The complete code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\margin{5cm}

\def\Sep{8mm}

\newcounter{myline}
\setcounter{myline}{0}

\newcommand{\LineB}{
\stepcounter{myline}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{
\coordinate (aux-\themyline);
\draw[red, double, double distance=1mm] (aux-\themyline-|myaux1) -- (aux-\themyline-|myaux2);}
}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=\margin}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw([shift={(\margin-\Sep-1mm,\margin-\Sep-1mm)}]current page.south west)  rectangle([shift={(-\margin+\Sep+1mm,-\margin+\Sep+1mm)}]current page.north east);
\draw([shift={(\margin-\Sep,\margin-\Sep)}]current page.south west)coordinate (myaux1)rectangle([shift={(-\margin+\Sep,-\margin+\Sep)}]current page.north east)coordinate (myaux2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]

\LineB

\lipsum[1]

\LineB

\lipsum[1]

\LineB

\end{document}
```

[image]

and with `\Sep=2mm` and `\margin=2cm`

[image]